# is getServiceLocator reading from module.config.php

Tags: php, zend-framework2

is the method getServiceLocator() reading config data only from module.config.php? Or is it also including other configuration information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `getServiceLocator()` is reading the configuration under the `service_manager` key from ALL Modules `module.config.php` as well as ALL Modules `getServiceConfig()` function. No more, no less.

You'd have to be more specific with your question if you are missing other information.

Comment: How do I get configuration from `global.php` or `local.php` in laminas API? It works when developer mode enabled but doesn't when I deploy it. Not sure what is happening.

Comment: Probably depends on your deployment - local.php are excluded from git by default. Probably that's your issue.

Comment: Even putting DB details in `global.php` is not working. Any thoughts? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61679035/config-in-global-php-or-local-php-not-working-but-works-from-module-config-php-i

Comment: @AdarshKhatri manually check on your server if the config files are all where you expect them to be. It's simply PHP, there is no loading differences on live vs. dev. On Production you might have config cache enabled, check /data or /data/cache or /cache - don't recall what is used. You might need to delete cached config from previous faulty deployment. If no cache and config files exist, then it's a different error. Dump the config and check what exactly your config is. And open a dedicated question on SO - this is outside the scope of a comment ;)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed info and your time. I had put my dedicated qst link on above comment. Thanks again.